# Text color depending on the text alignment

Tags: html, css

Using style sheets and attribute selectors, define styles that will allow texts placed on the page and saved in a paragraph to be displayed in different colors depending on the alignment of these texts on the page (for example, for texts aligned to the left it will be blue, for texts aligned to right - green) However, for texts placed in the h2 tag, the colors will be different depending on the font size used (for example, the font size is 16px - yellow etc.)
I completely don't know how to make this, could anyone help me?`

```html
<div>
<p>Text formatting</p>
<p>Text formatting</p>
<p>Text formatting</p>
<h2> Text formatting </h2>
<h2> Text formatting </h2>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Why don't you just put them in different classes and then edit those Classes in the css.

Comment: Because I have to do this like that, its school excersise not my own project

Comment: I see no way to achieve that without using classes and CSS only. JS could be the only solution for that. Besides, how do you want to align only specific parts to the elft or right without using classes within css?

Comment: I dont know man, thats the excersise description that's why I added this here because i thought there is some way to make this using css only, I had same thoughts about this, anyway thanks

Comment: wait, the question clearly states 'using style sheets and attribute selectors', so you can use CSS

Comment: You _could_ use `*[align="right"]` as a CSS selector. It's technically deprecated, but it is the only way to make this work. Similarly, you would have to use the `size="16px"` attribute instead of `style="font-size: 16px"` in order to be able to create a CSS rule using attribute selectors based on font size.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my answer won't get downvoted because of the invalid HTML.

So my first idea -- after reading *"using style sheets and attribute selectors"* -- was that it's not possible, unless your teachers want to use the **obsolete** `align` attribute on the `p` tags. I wouldn't be surprised though, so if that's the case, you could use `p[align="left"]` and `p[align="right"]` as attribute selectors.

But then I've seen that they also wanted to style `h2` tags based on their `font-size`, which is not possible by using CSS only. Unless they want to use another attribute, `size`.

`size` is a completely valid attribute, at least for `input` and `select` tags. You can't use on anything else. Do they want to use this though? Or maybe they just want to add a non-existing `font-size` attribute? I mean, it's a school exercise and we've all seen weird things...

Anyway, although it's not valid HTML, these examples work. I'm not sure if this is the correct answer though. I'd really appreciate it if you could tell us your instructor's solution, once they tell you. :)

```css
p[align="left"] {
  color: blue;
}

p[align="right"] {
  color: green;
}

h2[size="16px"] {
  background-color: #363636;
  color: yellow;
}

h2[font-size="16px"] {
  background-color: #363636;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text formatting</p>
  <p align="left">Text formatting</p>
  <p align="right">Text formatting</p>
  <h2>Text formatting</h2>
  <h2 size="16px">Text formatting</h2>
  <h2 font-size="16px">Text formatting</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So I just used classes for each selector and changed the size/color (whatever i needed to) and i got highest grade possible xD, don't even know what to say about that

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming back and telling me this lovely story about them asking students to use _attribute selectors_ and accepting class selectors. :) Congrats on the highest grade though ;)